# How to find a function's approximation?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, approximation, linear-approximation

I am having problems with the following question:

> Use the linear approximation $(1+x)^k\approx 1+kx$ to find an approximation for the function $f(x)$ for values of $x$ near zero $$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\left(1-\frac1{2+x}\right)^2}.$$

When $x$ approaches $0$, the fraction part approaches $\frac12$, which is far from $0$. So I wonder how I can apply the approximation formula given by the question to evaluate the linear approximation of $f(x).$

Comment: I have typed out your question - please refrain from posting images in the future as not all users can see them

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = \left( 1- \frac{1}{2+x}\right)^{2/3}
= \left( 1- \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1+x/2}\right)^{2/3}
= \left( 1- \frac{1}{2} (1+x/2)^{-1}\right)^{2/3}
$$
and $(1+x/2)^{-1} \approx 1-x/2$ so therefore
$$
f(x) \approx \left( 1- \frac{1}{2}(1-x/2)\right)^{2/3}
$$
... and so on. Maybe like this?

Comment: That is not a linear approximation ... lol

Comment: I have presented my idea to you, one which you can continue. It's not ready yet.

Comment: Okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?
$$
f(x) = \left( 1 - \frac 1 {2+x}\right)^{2/3} \approx 1 - \frac 2 {3(2+x)}
$$

Edit: indeed, this works when $\frac 1 {2+x}$ is small, which isn't the case when $x$ is close to zero.

Comment: In this problem, we are looking at $x \approx 0$, not $\frac{1}{2+x}\approx 0$. I also almost fell into this trap ...

Comment: Yep, that's the answer the solution offers. But I wonder why...

Comment: The approximation $(1 + y)^k \approx 1+yk$ holds when $y$ is near zero; you are applying it in a case where $y = -\frac1{2+x}$ is near $-1/2$.

Comment: Thank you, I am now able to understand the problem. I think the question doesn't make sense a lot. Next time, I'd rather use derivatives to figure out the approximation. Any way, thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest linear model could come from composition of Taylor series built at $x0$. You have
$$1-\frac{1}{x+2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{4}-\frac{x^2}{8}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Now, still using Taylor or binomial expansion
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{x+2}\right)^{2/3}=\frac{1}{2^{2/3}}+\frac{x}{3\ 2^{2/3}}-\frac{7 x^2}{36\ 2^{2/3}}+O\left(x^3\right)=\frac{1}{2^{2/3}}+\frac{x}{3\ 2^{2/3}}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which is not bad for $0.0 \leq x \leq 0.2$.